# multiple select in access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables... Records, Teams and Referees in my MS-Access
in the `Teams` table i have

```
Team_ID, Team_Name
```

in the `Referees` Table i have

```
Referee_ID and Referee_Name
```

In `Records` Table i have

```
Game_ID, Game_No, Play_Date, Win_Team, Lose_Team, Referee_1, Referee_2
```

Win_Team and Lose_Team from Records is Foreign Key to Team_ID in Teams Table.
and Referee_1 and Referee_2 is Foreign Key to Referee ID from Referees Table.

My question is that it is possible that i can query the Team_Name of the Records.Win_Team and Records.Lose_Team? also with the Referees...

i try this one,

```
SELECT distinct Records.Game_No, Records.Play_Date, IIf([Records.W_Team]=[Teams.Team_ID],Teams.Team_Name) AS Expr1, IIf([Records.L_Team]=[Teams.Team_ID],Teams.Team_Name) AS Expr2
FROM Records, Teams 
where Records.W_Team = Teams.Team_ID
or Teams.Team_ID = Records.L_Team
group by
Records.Game_No,
Records.Play_Date,
Records.W_Team,
Teams.Team_ID,
Teams.Team_Name,
Records.L_Team
```

but the output is [image]

do anyone have an idea about my situation? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the Teams twice. Just imagine that you have two `Teams` tables: Join one to the winner ID and one to the loser ID:

```
SELECT Records.Game_No, Records.Play_Date, 
       Team_Winners.Team_Name, Team_Losers.Team_Name
  FROM (Records INNER JOIN Teams AS Team_Winners
        ON Records.Win_Team = Team_Winners.Team_ID)
       INNER JOIN Teams AS Team_Losers
       ON Records.Lose_Team = Team_Losers.Team_ID
```

The same is true for the referees, you also need to join them twice (this is left as an exercise ;-)).